# ListView.setItemChecked() in bindView() takes away focus from EditText i just clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, android-cursoradapter

I have an Edittext and a CheckedTextView in a listview item (the layout implements Checkable). When I click on the EditText, the bindView() method of the CursorAdapter calls ListView.setItemChecked() (I do this to restore CheckMarks that may have to be restored after clearing a filter). However, ListView.setItemChecked() seems to immediately take away the focus (or something else happening here?) from the EditText I just clicked, so now I can't use the EditText anymore.

I there a way to call ListView.setItemChecked() inside bindView() without such a sideeffect? I already tried calling ListView.setItemChecked() after adapter.getFilter().filter() (outside of bindView()) but it seems in this case the new item list is not available just yet, because the filtering is done in a background thread.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: use FilterListener class like this

adapter.getFilter().filter("", new FilterListener() {

```
  @Override
  public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
      if (selected.contains((int) adapter.getItemId(i)))
        listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT: strictly speaking this is not an answer because I still don't know why setItemChecked can't be used in bindView() without intering with the edittext